# How to find automatically open, high, low and close values and display candlestick and ohlc chart

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

I have the following code. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jennysayhello/L5hHB/) Which the type button idea borrow from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/qVajq/)

my javascript code:

```
 $(function () {   $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlc.json&callback=?', function (data) {
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    timezoneOffset: 7 * 60
                }
            });

        // Create the chart
        var end = 1363935600000;
        var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                inputEnabled: false,
                selected: 0,
                buttonTheme: {
                    width: null
                },
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 6,
                    text: 'past 7 days'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 14,
                    text: 'past 15 days'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 29,
                    text: 'past 30 days'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 59,
                    text: 'past 60 days'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 179,
                    text: 'past 180 days'
                }]
            },

            xAxis: {
                max: end,
                type: 'datetime',
                minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
            },
            navigator: {
                enabled: false
            },
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 3
                }
            }]
        });
        // Toggle point markers
        var enableMarkers = true;
        $('#markers').click(function () {
            chart.series[0].update({
                marker: {
                    enabled: enableMarkers,
                    radius: 5,
                    fillColor: '#0000FF'
                }
            });
            enableMarkers = !enableMarkers;
        });

        // Toggle point markers
        var color = false;
        $('#color').click(function () {
            chart.series[0].update({
                color: color ? null : Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            });
            color = !color;
        });

        // Set type
        $.each(['line', 'spline', 'area', 'areaspline', 'candlestick', 'ohlc'], function (i, type) {
            $('#' + type).click(function () {
                chart.series[0].update({
                    type: type
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

my html code:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>
<button id="markers">Toggle point markers</button>
<button id="color">Toggle color</button>
<button id="line" style="margin-left: 2em">Line</button>
<button id="spline">Spline</button>
<button id="area">Area</button>
<button id="areaspline">Area spline</button>
<button id="ohlc">OHLC</button>
<button id="candlestick">Candlestick</button>
```

Update the question:
it works fine in with the sample dataset. 
But if i change the data set below:
1279609200000   74

```
1279695600000   685
1279782000000   1123
1279868400000   666
1279954800000   166
1280041200000   84
1280127600000   302
1280214000000   492
1280300400000   571
1280386800000   602
1280473200000   583
1280559600000   570
1280646000000   493
1280732400000   685
1280818800000   702
1280905200000   549
```

how to display the candlestick and ohlc chart? thanks.

Comment: get the JSON file from http://www.highcharts.com/sample/data/jsonp.php and save it on your local machine, may be that works !

Comment: even if I change the json file as local file, it still cannot display chart in chrome. And right now the firefox cannot display the candlestick and OHLC type in highstocks

Comment: do you get any error in the console ?

Comment: I think you are missing including jquery version file !

Comment: in the local html, I include jquery version file. in jsfiddle I don't have to include

Comment: any errors in console ??

Comment: no error in console. You can test the code in jsfiddle

Comment: Becuase your data set contains only y value, where you have low/close/high?